# Read colorScheme in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI, and I want save `colorScheme` to `@State` wraper but it does not work, it does update the *wrong* value for `@State`, how I should solve this problem?

My code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    
    @State private var color: String = String()
    
    var body: some View {

        
        Text(color)
            .onAppear() {
                
                if      (colorScheme == .light) {
                    color = "light"
                    
                }
                else {
                    color = "dark"
                    
                }
                
            }
            .onChange(of: colorScheme) { _ in

                if      (colorScheme == .light) {
                    color = "light"
                    
                }
                else {
                    color = "dark"
                    
                }

            }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.onChange is essentially a willSet. The value is changing, but it hasn't changed yet. If you change it to:

```
    .onChange(of: colorScheme) { newValue in
        if      (newValue == .light) {
            color = "light"
        }
        else {
            color = "dark"
        }
    }
```

it will work. Tested Xcode 12.2, iOS 14.2.